# Angular component cannot be navigated to with routing

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 components, and I have added routing, however, only 1 component is accessible for navigation. the other component cannot be navigated to, and I wonder what the issue is? I will below paste my app module, my app routing module, then finally my html template.

My 2 components are named "view-emp" and "edit-emp". edit-emp works fine, view-emp doesn't work. When I click the link to navigate to view-emp, nothing happens, I simply remain in the home screen. However, when I click on the edit-emp link, I do get navigated to 4200/edit-emp and I do see the component

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ViewEmpComponent } from './view-emp/view-emp.component';
import { EditEmpComponent } from './edit-emp/edit-emp.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ViewEmpComponent,
    EditEmpComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ViewEmpComponent } from './view-emp/view-emp.component';
import { EditEmpComponent } from './edit-emp/edit-emp.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'view-emp', component: ViewEmpComponent},
  {path: 'edit-emp', component: EditEmpComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<p>ello welcome to angular routing</p>

<nav>
    <ul>
      <a routerLink="/view-emp" routerLinkActive="active">View employee</a>
      <a routerLink="/edit-emp" routerLinkActive="active">Edit employee</a>
    </ul>
  </nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: You mentioned that when you click on the `View employee` nothing happens, even the router doesn't change? It should be something related to the `routerLinkActive `, try to reverse the <a> tag orders, and if it not work, try to remove it to test.

Comment: @RaphaelMarques I tried removing <a> tag of view-emp, and I tried reversing the order of the <a> tags, still nothing changes

Comment: Not removing <a> tag, but `routerLinkActive`. Another question, if you add it manually to the router, does it work for both?

Comment: @RaphaelMarques I tried removing routerLinkActive, does nothing. If I tried to add what manually?

Comment: the `/view-emp` to the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding the CommonModule in app.module.ts imports?

Comment: Does nothing, chief

Comment: are you still facing this issue? I tried to replicate your changes on a new application and they seem to work as expected. Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: I'm unsure about version, I have found out the error. It turns out there was a fault within my component, which stops the HTML from appearing. The code compiled fine. I did something wrong in the ngOnInit() method and constructor